# Download button not working in gnomelook

Tags: 22.04

I am trying to download this theme: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1267246/ but the download button couldn't work.

[image]

Can y'all teach me how to let the download button work again? Thanks.

Comment: No idea how to fix a button BUT try this method for your theme https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-nordic-gtk-theme-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Use the direct link: https://files04.pling.com/api/files/download/j/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjE3MDY0ODA0NzUiLCJ1IjpudWxsLCJsdCI6ImZpbGVwcmV2aWV3IiwicyI6IjAxM2ZhOTljYWNhYTBhODU3OWU4OGNjZWUzYjZiYjg1MjE3ZDMyMmY0NDZhNDRlOWI4ZDQ1YWU4YjQwZmQ0OWZlNGE2MGI4Yjc0ZjgwNmYyYjlkYTAxZTc2OWMwMGQxMTJiZTk2ZDZhNTc2NzgzNDcwOTcyOTk3MWUzNDRlNzA2IiwidCI6MTcwNjk1MjMwOCwic3RmcCI6bnVsbCwic3RpcCI6bnVsbH0.9eGxHYzTjAeNwv5LfN26a6_ja0uAxTkEdUX9RZzuvZo/Nordic-darker.tar.xz

## Option 2

Use the command line ([adapted from another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743991/524752)):

```bash
curl -Lfs https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1267246/loadFiles | jq -r '.files | first.version as $v | .[] | select(.version == $v).url' | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge' | grep Nordic-darker\\.tar | xargs wget
```

## Option 3

The button not working is caused by the advertisements trying to show, and the countdown added to force you to watch them. We can get rid of this:

1. Uninstall all extensions from your browser
2. Install https://ublockorigin.com/ . It has code for skipping countdowns
3. Go back to https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1267246/ and try again